# Edittext and a button followed by recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

**I have an empty `Activity` with `RelativeLayout` and `RecyclerView`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavilayout_widthor="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**I need an `EditText` and a button to be added before `RecyclerView`**.
    I guess `RecyclerView's` padding height should be changed but not sure! Please help me

Comment: Do you need something like a search above the recycler view?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: @ V V yes, you're right. I need this instead of search view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. Make your parent layout as Linear layout, your views will get stacked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Change the LinearLayout to **`"Vertical"`** orientation
- Use **`android:layout_weight`** Property.

> Indicates how much of the extra space in the LinearLayout is allocated
>   to the view associated with these LayoutParams.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_ONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

You can try with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavilayout_widthor="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">


   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_ONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

is this you want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LinearLayout` before `RecyclerView` and and provide them an ID(e.g. temp) and use `RelativeLayout` property  `layout_below` with the `RecyclerView`, like this  `android:layout_below="@id/temp"`(it will make sure that your `RecyclerView` will always below then `LinearLayout`), Now Add your `Button` and `EditText` into that `LinearLayout` (Make sure that `LinearLayout` should be `wrap_content` into height)

Use this code, Edit according to your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavilayout_widthor="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/temp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EditText"/>

           <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```